# no such element: Unable to locate element error - scraping with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I can see this question was asked before and browsed through some of the answers with no luck. I am having trouble scraping data from sports betting site which I need for my analysis. I am getting: no such element: Unable to locate element error. Also, there is a chance betting sites may prohibit scraping data from their sites but I can't confirm it. Also, some suggestions from previously answered questions suggest some issues with iframe(which I am not too familiar with). Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://superbet.pl/zaklady-bukmacherskie/live')
name1 = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="event-4102570"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')
print(name1)
```

This is part of my page source(can get only 30k of characters in the post):

```
<html lang="en" class=" unicoderange" style="--vh:12.48px;"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover"><title>Zakłady live - obstawiaj zakłady na żywo w Superbet</title><style> .webpush-window-body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}#webpush-window { position: absolute; text-align: center; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 50%; opacity: 0;}#webpush-window-image { height: 128px; margin-bottom: 10px;}#webpush-window-title { font-size: 22px; padding: 0 5px;}#webpush-window-text { color: #333333; margin-top: 15px; padding: 0 5px; line-height: 22px;}#webpush-custom-prompt { position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; width: 320px; max-width: 100%; padding: 10px; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -170px; background-color: rgb(231,232,233); box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888888; color: #000000; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;}#webpush-custom-prompt-image { width: 64px; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px;}#webpush-custom-prompt-title { margin-left: 90px; margin-top: 4px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px;}#webpush-custom-prompt-text { font-size: 10px; margin-left: 90px; margin-top: 5px; line-height: 15px;}#webpush-custom-prompt-buttons { padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; float: right;}#webpush-custom-prompt-button1 { background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #f6f6f6)); background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%); background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0); background-color:#ffffff; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; border-radius:6px; border:1px solid #dcdcdc; display:inline-block; color:#666666; font-size:12px; padding:4px 24px; margin-right: 6px; cursor: default;}#webpush-custom-prompt-button2 { background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #33bdef), color-stop(1, #019ad2)); background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%); background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#33bdef', endColorstr='#019ad2',GradientType=0); background-color:#33bdef; -moz-border-radius:6px; -webkit-border-radius:6px; border-radius:6px; border:1px solid #057fd0; display:inline-block; color:#ffffff; font-size:12px; padding:4px 24px; cursor: default;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-position-left { left: 16px;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-position-right { right: 16px;}#webpush-notification-center { position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; display: none; overflow-y: auto;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-layout-panel { top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 300px; max-width: 90%;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-layout-popup { top: 20px; height: 400px; width: 300px; max-width: 90%; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-position-left { left: 0;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-position-right { right: 0;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-color-light { background: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888888; color: #666666;}#webpush-notification-center.webpush-notification-center-color-dark { background: #555555; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888888; color: #ffffff;}#webpush-notification-center-header { height: 40px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; position: relative;}#webpush-notification-center-subscription { padding: 0 50px 0 8px;}#webpush-notification-center-subscription-switch-container { float: left; padding-top: 15px;}#webpush-notification-center-subscription-status { float: left; font-size: 12px; line-height: 40px; letter-spacing: 0.1em;}#webpush-notification-center-subscription .webpush-onoffswitch { display: inline-block; margin-right: 16px; margin-left: 8px;}#webpush-notification-center-icon { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 20px 20px;}#webpush-notification-center-title { font-size: 13px; line-height: 40px; letter-spacing: 0.1em; text-align: center;}#webpush-notification-center-close { position: absolute; top: 14px; right: 8px; height: 12px; width: 12px; font-size: 12px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 12px 12px; cursor: pointer;}#webpush-notification-center-list { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: absolute; top: 41px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}.webpush-notification-center-item { padding: 8px 8px; position: relative; font-size: 12px; min-height: 48px; cursor: pointer;}.webpush-notification-center-color-light .webpush-notification-center-item { border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;}.webpush-notification-center-color-dark .webpush-notification-center-item { border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;}.webpush-notification-center-color-light .webpush-notification-center-item:hover { background-color: #f3f3f3;}.webpush-notification-center-color-dark .webpush-notification-center-item:hover { background-color: #808080;}.webpush-notification-center-item-image { width: 48px; height: 48px; float: left;}.webpush-notification-center-item-title { padding-left: 58px; font-weight: bold;}.webpush-notification-center-item-title p { margin: 0px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-text { padding-left: 58px; margin-top: 4px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-text p { margin: 0px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-date { padding-left: 58px; margin-top: 3px; font-size: 11px; color: #b7b7b7;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card { padding: 0;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card .webpush-notification-center-item-image { width: 100%; height: auto; float: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card .webpush-notification-center-item-title { padding: 5px 7px; font-weight: bold;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card .webpush-notification-center-item-text-container { padding: 0px 7px 5px 7px; margin: 0px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card .webpush-notification-center-item-text { padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; margin-top: 0px;}.webpush-notification-center-item-webinbox-card .webpush-notification-center-item-date { display: none;}#webpush-notification-center-loader { text-align: center; padding: 8px; height: 15px;}#webpush-notification-center-title-loader { text-align: center; padding-top: 14px; height: 40px;}#webpush-notification-center-placeholder { font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px; padding: 5px 16px;}#webpush-notification-center-load-more { font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;}.webpush-notification-center-color-light #webpush-notification-center-load-more { border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;}.webpush-notification-center-color-dark #webpush-notification-center-load-more { border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;}.webpush-notification-center-color-light #webpush-notification-center-load-more:hover { background-color: #f3f3f3;}.webpush-notification-center-color-dark #webpush-notification-center-load-more:hover { background-color: #808080;}#webpush-notification-center-open { position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; top: 20px; height: 60px; width: 60px; border-radius: 50%; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; line-height: 60px; background-size: 30px 30px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition: 0.7s ease;}#webpush-notification-center-open:hover { box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); transition: 0.7s ease; transform-origin: center;}#webpush-notification-center-open[badge-count]:after { position: absolute; right: -3px; top: -3px; content: attr(badge-count); font-size: 12px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 50%; line-height: 12px; color: #ffffff; background: #ed1c25; text-align: center; min-width: 12px; font-weight: bold;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-light { background-color: #1d87c8;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-light:hover { background-color: #2298e1;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-dark { background-color: #555555;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-dark:hover { background-color: #5a606e;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-custom { background-color: #1d87c8;}#webpush-notification-center-open.webpush-notification-center-color-custom:hover { background-color: #2298e1;}#webpush-local-notification-stack { position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 20px; z-index: 9999999; margin-left: 20px;}.webpush-local-notification { background: #ffffff; max-width: 370px; width: 100%; min-width: 250px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #888888; position: relative; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; margin-bottom: 10px; min-height: 80px; cursor: default;}.webpush-local-notification-close { position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 8px; cursor: pointer;}.webpush-local-notification-image { width: 80px; height: 80px; float: left;}.webpush-local-notification-title { padding-left: 95px; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 35px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #444444;}.webpush-local-notification-text { padding-left: 95px; padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px;}.webpush-onoffswitch-container { line-height: 10px;}.webpush-onoffswitch { position: relative; width: 30px; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;}.webpush-onoffswitch-checkbox { display: none;}.webpush-onoffswitch-label { display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; height: 10px; padding: 0; line-height: 10px; border-radius: 16px; background-color: rgba(158,158,158,0.5);}.webpush-onoffswitch-label:before { content: ''; display: block; width: 16px; margin: -3px; background-color: rgb(158,158,158); position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 18px; border-radius: 16px;}.webpush-onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .webpush-onoffswitch-label { background-color: rgba(47,169,214,0.5);}.webpush-onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .webpush-onoffswitch-label .webpush-onoffswitch-inner { margin-left: 0;}.webpush-onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .webpush-onoffswitch-label:before { right: 0; background-color: rgb(47,169,214); box-shadow: none;}.webpush-onoffswitch-tooltip { display: none; position: absolute; min-width: 50px; max-width: 200px; min-height: 16px; max-height: 200px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); color: #fff; padding: 8px; border-radius: 2px; z-index: 3000; line-height: 16px; font-size: 12px; opacity: 0.9; -webkit-transition: opacity 75ms linear; -moz-transition: opacity 75ms linear; -ms-transition: opacity 75ms linear; transition: opacity 75ms linear; top: 32px; left: 15px;}.webpush-reset { animation: none; animation-delay: 0s; animation-direction: normal; animation-duration: 0s; animation-fill-mode: none; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-name: none; animation-play-state: running; animation-timing-function: ease; backface-visibility: visible; background: 0; background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position: 0 0; background-position-x: 0; background-position-y: 0; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto auto; border: 0; border-style: none; border-width: medium; border-color: inherit; border-bottom: 0; border-bottom-color: inherit; border-bottom-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-right-radius: 0; border-bottom-style: none; border-bottom-width: medium; border-collapse: separate; border-image: none; border-left: 0; border-left-color: inherit; border-left-style: none; border-left-width: medium; border-radius: 0; border-right: 0; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-style: none; border-right-width: medium; border-spacing: 0; border-top: 0; border-top-color: inherit; border-top-left-radius: 0; border-top-right-radius: 0; border-top-style: none; border-top-width: medium; bottom: auto; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: content-box; caption-side: top; clear: none; clip: auto; color: inherit; columns: auto; column-count: auto; column-fill: balance; column-gap: normal; column-rule: medium none currentColor; column-rule-color: currentColor; column-rule-style: none; column-rule-width: 0; column-span: 1; column-width: auto; content: normal; counter-increment: none; counter-reset: none; cursor: auto; direction: ltr; display: inline; empty-cells: show; float: none; /*font: normal;*/ font-family: inherit; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; height: auto; hyphens: none; left: auto; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; list-style: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: disc; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; max-height: none; max-width: none; min-height: 0; min-width: 0; opacity: 1; orphans: 0; outline: 0; outline-color: invert; outline-style: none; outline-width: medium; overflow: visible; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-top: 0; page-break-after: auto; page-break-before: auto; page-break-inside: auto; perspective: none; perspective-origin: 50% 50%; position: static; right: auto; tab-size: 8; table-layout: auto; text-align: inherit; text-align-last: auto; text-decoration: none; text-decoration-line: none; text-decoration-style: solid; text-indent: 0; text-shadow: none; text-transform: none; top: auto; transform: none; transform-style: flat; transition: none; transition-delay: 0s; transition-duration: 0s; transition-property: none; transition-timing-function: ease; unicode-bidi: normal; vertical-align: baseline; visibility: visible; white-space: normal; widows: 0; width: auto; word-spacing: normal; z-index: auto;}.webpush-loader { display: inline-block; position: relative; vertical-align: middle; width: 48px; height: 16px;}.webpush-loader div { position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 21px; width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color: #666666; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-animation: growDot 1s linear .15s infinite; -moz-animation: growDot 1s linear .15s infinite; -ms-animation: growDot 1s linear .15s infinite; -o-animation: growDot 1s linear .15s infinite; animation: growDot 1s linear .15s infinite;}.webpush-loader div:before { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -15px; width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color: #666666; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-animation: growDot 1s linear 0s infinite; -moz-animation: growDot 1s linear 0s infinite; -ms-animation: growDot 1s linear 0s infinite; -o-animation: growDot 1s linear 0s infinite; animation: growDot 1s linear 0s infinite;}.webpush-loader div:after { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 15px; width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color: #666666; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; background-clip: padding-box; -webkit-animation: growDot 1s linear .3s infinite; -moz-animation: growDot 1s linear .3s infinite; -ms-animation: growDot 1s linear .3s infinite; -o-animation: growDot 1s linear .3s infinite; animation: growDot 1s linear .3s infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes growDot { 0% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)';  filter: alpha(opacity=70);  opacity: 0.7;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; } 25% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)';  filter: alpha(opacity=100);  opacity: 1;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #666666; } 50% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)';  filter: alpha(opacity=70);  opacity: 0.7;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; } 100% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)';  filter: alpha(opacity=60);  opacity: 0.6;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; }}@keyframes growDot { 0% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)';  filter: alpha(opacity=70);  opacity: 0.7;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; } 25% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)';  filter: alpha(opacity=100);  opacity: 1;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #666666; } 50% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)';  filter: alpha(opacity=70);  opacity: 0.7;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; } 100% {  -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)';  filter: alpha(opacity=60);  opacity: 0.6;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #666666; }}.webpush-balloon { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 100% 100%;}.webpush-balloon-light, .webpush-balloon-dark, .webpush-balloon-custom { background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');}.webpush-clearfix { clear: both;}.webpush-swal2-title p { margin: 0;} </style><style>.webpush-notification-center-icon-bell {background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' id='Layer_1' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 459.334 459.334' style='enable-background:new 0 0 459.334 459.334;' xml:space='preserve' width='512px' height='512px'> <g> <g> <g> <path d='M175.216,404.514c-0.001,0.12-0.009,0.239-0.009,0.359c0,30.078,24.383,54.461,54.461,54.461 s54.461-24.383,54.461-54.461c0-0.12-0.008-0.239-0.009-0.359H175.216z' fill='%23999999'/> <path d='M403.549,336.438l-49.015-72.002c0-22.041,0-75.898,0-89.83c0-60.581-43.144-111.079-100.381-122.459V24.485 C254.152,10.963,243.19,0,229.667,0s-24.485,10.963-24.485,24.485v27.663c-57.237,11.381-100.381,61.879-100.381,122.459 c0,23.716,0,76.084,0,89.83l-49.015,72.002c-5.163,7.584-5.709,17.401-1.419,25.511c4.29,8.11,12.712,13.182,21.887,13.182 H383.08c9.175,0,17.597-5.073,21.887-13.182C409.258,353.839,408.711,344.022,403.549,336.438z' fill='%23999999'/> </g> </g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>");}.webpush-notification-center-icon-close {background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' id='Capa_1' x='0px' y='0px' width='512px' height='512px' viewBox='0 0 357 357' style='enable-background:new 0 0 357 357;' xml:space='preserve'> <g> <g id='close'> <polygon points='357,35.7 321.3,0 178.5,142.8 35.7,0 0,35.7 142.8,178.5 0,321.3 35.7,357 178.5,214.2 321.3,357 357,321.3 214.2,178.5' fill='%23999999'/> </g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> <g> </g> </svg>");}</style><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-5K6NJGJ1F8&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-1693628.js?sv=7"></script><script gtm="GTM-PSKZC66" type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-MJR4LQS"></script><script async="" src="https://prod.webpu.sh/ic6rRg2T8JGsA5AufXy2EVCbodNL0r7U/sdk.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PSKZC66&amp;gtm_auth=nm0VsPiCyoBS0Xsaz2QatQ&amp;gtm_preview=env-1&amp;gtm_cookies_win=x"></script><script src="https://scorealarm-stats.freetls.fastly.net/localization/superbet/web/pl_translations.js"></script><script>window.translationMessages = translations;
        translations = null;</script><script src="/static/js/gtm.js"></script><script src="/static/js/one-trust.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" type="text/javascript" data-language="pl" data-domain-script="abb3dd46-d9ca-4d6c-b553-9aec751bf4ae"></script><script src="https://old.superbet.pl/rest/SBWeb.Models.Session/returnSiteParams.js"></script><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/img/icons/favicon.ico"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/static/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/static/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png"><link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="cAHJ7okzAxP1Bz422yebec0zmUMnZYD5NkqszVG3Ris"><!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/icons/favicon.ico"><![endif]--><meta name="theme-color" content="#EA060A"><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#fd0104"><meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="##fd0104"><link rel="mask-icon" href="/static/img/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#fd0104"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/img/apple-touch-icon.png"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#EA060A"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="superbet.country"><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000"><script src="https://cdn.seondf.com/js/v4/agent.js"></script><script src="/static/js/xtremePush.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/chunk-vendors.21ae673b.js"></script><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/app.904e7ee0.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/4851.657224c0.css"><script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/6.30.0/otBannerSdk.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script><style id="onetrust-style">#onetrust-banner-sdk{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}#onetrust-banner-sdk .onetrust-vendors-list-handler{cursor:pointer;color:#1f96db;font-size:inherit;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;margin-left:5px}#onetrust-banner-sdk .onetrust-vendors-list-handler:hover{color:#1f96db}#onetrust-banner-sdk:focus{outline:2px solid #000;outline-offset:-2px}#onetrust-banner-sdk a:focus{outline:2px solid #000}#onetrust-banner-sdk #onetrust-accept-btn-handler,#onetrust-banner-sdk #onetrust-reject-all-handler,#onetrust-banner-sdk #onetrust-pc-btn-handler{outline-offset:1px}#onetrust-banner-sdk .ot-close-icon,#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-close-icon,#ot-sync-ntfy .ot-close-icon{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;height:12px;width:12px}#onetrust-banner-sdk .powered-by-logo,#onetrust-banner-sdk .ot-pc-footer-logo a,#onetrust-pc-sdk .powered-by-logo,#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-pc-footer-logo a,#ot-sync-ntfy .powered-by-logo,#ot-sync-ntfy .ot-pc-footer-logo a{background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;height:25px;width:152px;display:block}#onetrust-banner-sdk h3 *,#onetrust-banner-sdk h4 *,#onetrust-banner-sdk h6 *,#onetrust-banner-sdk button *,#onetrust-banner-sdk a[data-parent-id] *,#onetrust-pc-sdk h3 *,#onetrust-pc-sdk h4 *,#onetrust-pc-sdk h6 *,#onetrust-pc-sdk button *,#onetrust-pc-sdk a[data-parent-id] *,#ot-sync-ntfy h3 *,#ot-sync-ntfy h4 *,#ot-sync-ntfy h6 *,#ot-sync-ntfy button *,#ot-sync-ntfy a[data-parent-id] *{font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;color:inherit}#onetrust-banner-sdk .ot-hide,#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-hide,#ot-sync-ntfy .ot-hide{display:none !important}#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-sdk-row .ot-sdk-column{padding:0}#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-sdk-container{padding-right:0}#onetrust-pc-sdk .ot-sdk-row{flex-direction:initial;width:100%}#onetrust-pc-sdk [type="checkbox"]:checked,#onetrust-pc-sdk [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked){pointer-events:initial}#onetrust-pc-sdk [type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before,#onetrust-pc-sdk [type="checkbox"]:disabled+label:after,#onetrust-pc-sdk [type="checkbox"]:disabled+label{pointer-events:none;opacity:0.7}#onetrust-pc-sdk #vendor-list-content{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0)}#onetrust-pc-sdk li input[type="checkbox"]{z-index:1}#onetrust-pc-sdk li .ot-checkbox label{z-index:2}#onetrust-pc-sdk li .ot-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{height:auto;width:auto}#onetrust-pc-sdk li .host-title a,#onetrust-pc-sdk li .ot-host-name a,#onetrust-pc-sdk li .accordion-text,#onetrust-pc-sdk li .ot-acc-txt{z-index:2;position:relative}#onetrust-pc-sdk input{margin:3px
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?
If I could get just one element from this page I believe I could get everything I need.

Comment: Could be but are you 100% sure? I tried scraping different elements with different methods(by.id, by.tag, etc.) with no luck.

Comment: Website is prohibited at my end, can you please post the page html, `print(driver.page_source)` and add it your question.

Comment: It seems there is a limit to the number of characters you can type in the comment box. My page source is about 150k characters too long. Any other idea how I can get that for you?

Comment: @JapoJapic : Edit your question and add there, not in the comment box.

Comment: Try adding a wait statement or use time.sleep to allow the page to render before executing the find_element method

Comment: Only 30k characters are allowed in the original post so don't think you will get much out of what I added.

Comment: @Alexander can you put that in the code as what I am doing is not working, Thanks.

Comment: @JapoJapic : You are right, last thing to do, go to chrome dev tool, copy the html of the `span` tag and also check parent node of the `span` tag having `iframe` or `frame` tag, if so post that html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting a bit to let the page render prior to running the `find_element` method.  I use time.sleep in the example below for the sake of simplicity, but there are more practical and elegant solutions using the selenium [waits API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://superbet.pl/zaklady-bukmacherskie/live')
time.sleep(2)  # pause code to let page render.
name1 = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="event-4102570"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')
print(name1)
```